# 7 and 4.7 inch tab/phone come under normal screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-screen, android-resolution

i have bsnl penta 7" tab. It comes under normal, mdpi, 455x800, screen size is ~5.4"(but tab is 7") when checked via code.

The real problem is, when running my application it loads images, size etc from \res\drawable folder (not a problem with mdpi also not loading from /res/drawable-large). So that the images and font will be small. Similar problem is occurring in some other smart phones too. How can be handled it.

I also configured an emulator similar spec to that tab and it works perfectly.

thanks in advance

Comment: try it with folder named large-mdpi

Comment: You should create new device with which density option you want.

Comment: @Tamilselvan i tried it  before and as i said the tab come under normal not large by checking via code.

Comment: @alicanbatur "new device" means creating an emulator using this spec.. if so i created and it works perfect.. but in case of real device it is not..

Comment: Can you share device name with me ? @Abin

Comment: @alicanbatur BSNL penta is701c version 4.0.3(version is updated)

Comment: @alicanbatur this link got some of its spec http://www.pantel.in/tablet/t-pad-is701c-41.html

Comment: @Abin i look it up. I'm sorry i dont get problem. If the problem is images, you check they are in right place. For eg, if you put same images in different folders(drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi ..) it wont change anything. You need different images for different screen sizes.

Comment: @alicanbatur i may explain by example, there is an image of mango in drawable folder and orange in drawable-large folder under resource folder where both the image is named as ic_fruit. When we run on this 7 inch tab image of orange is to be loaded. But in my case image of mango is loading. I hope u understand me. -Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45186/discussion-between-alicanbatur-and-abin)